# How to combine two types of dynamic property in SQL Server 2000 DTS?

Tags: sql-server-2000, dts

Basically, I can't find a way to combine two types. For example, supposing I want a connection to refer to a text file that is held in a path identified by one of the environment variables, and whose filename is a string form of the current day.
I can use SQL to set the filename, and an environment  variable to set the path, but I can't seem to find a way to join the two into a full file path which can then be used as a Text File connection. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found a way to get the same effect here :

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DTS/2851/

with an ActiveX script task.